# Timer won't stop firing a function

Tags: javascript, function, timer

```
video.onloadedmetadata = function start(){ //invoke
    var thethis = this;
    var event;
    var timeout;
    function func(){
        mainFunction(event); //this is supposed to fire only once, instead it fires constantly.
        console.log("sending!!!"); //This won't stop show up in the console
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        console.log(event);
    }


    video.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
        event = e;
        outsideElement = false;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(func, 600);
    });

    video.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ //mouse is out of elem
        outsideElement = true; //extra security, really make sure not to fire Mainfunction will check - if it's indeed outsideElement then it won't work properly.
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }); //don't fire mainFunction in this case


}
```

What I am trying to do is pretty simple, though in reality doesn't work. Once a user moves his mouse on my video, and he stops on a certain spot for half a sec, a function called mainFunction is supposed to fire once. Next time he moves his mouse and stops on a spot, it's supposed to happen again - but instead it won't stop firing mainFunction. I can't use jQuery for several reasons, so please - if you can help, just without any libraries.

JS FIDDLE: (check the console too)
https://jsfiddle.net/7con1p04/1/

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle or something to test your code?

Comment: check it out, just did

Comment: Checking the console it triggers only once and only when I stop. When I'm moving the mouse inside the video it doesn't get fired unless i stop again (and it's fired only once) as far as i understood your question this is the behaviour you're looking for, isn't it?

Comment: What you describe is what I try to do. I even took my mouse battery out and put the mouse on the vid and it still won't stop firing, so I really don't know what is wrong over here. I am using Chrome, btw.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y24h3ez9/) that boils your functionality down to just the timer/mousemove delay (same code, just everything else stripped out):

```
var timeout;

function func(){
    console.log('fire');
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(func, 600);
});
```

It works flawlessly.

I'd look elsewhere than the timer/delay logic itself. At this point if I were you I'd start putting separate console.log calls in all of those functions and making sure they're only being called when you expect.

Comment: Check the console in what you just sent. it won't stop firing "fire", although I said I need the "fire" console to fire only once - incase the user stopped on a certain spot for half a second. While he is IDLE, nothing should happen.

Comment: @user1938653 - Considering my only output was the console it's a pretty good bet that I checked the console before saying it worked :) And for me I move the mouse onto doc and nothing happens until I stop...then a half second later it fires. Then I leave it and nothing happens...unless I move it again and then stop it again...in which case a half second after I stop it fires one more time. If you're not seeing that then you need to indicate what browser/system you're on, because it's obviously something specific to that.

Comment: @user1938653 - FYI, same for the jsfiddle you post. The event only fires once at a time after I move the mouse and then stop for a half second, then does nothing until I move and stop and wait a half second again. Fred reports the same results. You are the only one seeing a problem, bud. I did both these tests on Chrome like you. There's something up with your system, not your code.